# Custom Logout URL for AWS SSO connected with External Identity via SAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, identity, aws-sso

Recently started using AWS SSO for managing access to the AWS Management console. I also connected the external identity using SAML.

But I wonder how I can give a custom logout URL for the AWS SSO?

I can't find any documentation, which talks about external identity logout https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtosignout.html